# Rage Morale bonus and Moment of Greatness

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, rage, morale

How does the morale bonus to STR when raging interact with the spell Moment of Greatness when making an attack?

Can you double the +4 morale bonus to STR only on the attack, only the damage roll, both, or either?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### It applies to either the attack roll or damage roll, but not both.

The benefit of [*Moment of Greatness*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/moment-of-greatness/) is limited to "one roll or check" per affected creature. Then the creature no longer benefits from the spell.

> If the affected creature is benefiting from a morale bonus of any type, it can double that morale bonus on one roll or check, before making the roll. Once an affected creature uses this spell’s effect, the spell is discharged for that subject.

If the attack or damage roll incorporates the creature's Stength modifier in its calculation, and the creature is raging (and has a morale bonus to Strength), then it qualifies.

So you can either:

- Double the morale bonus to Strength when calculating the attack roll, or
- Double the morale bonus to Strength when calculating the damage roll.

---

Suppose you normally rage with a +4 morale bonus to Strength. Then here's the math:

The formula for your attack bonus is usually:

`BAB + (STR modifier + 2 from the rage bonus) + misc`

and with *Moment of Greatness*, the bonus effectively increases by +2:

`BAB + (STR modifier + 4 from the doubled rage bonus) + misc`

If you use a two-handed weapon (let's say a greatsword), then the formula for your damage is usually:

`2d6 + (STR modifier + 2 from the rage bonus) x 1.5 = 2d6 + (STR modifier x 1.5) + 3`

and with *Moment of Greatness*, the damage effectively increases by +3:

`2d6 + (STR modifier + 4 from the doubled rage bonus) x 1.5 = 2d6 + (STR modifier x 1.5) + 6`

Comment: So with a two handed weapon this equates to +2 to the attack or +3 damage